# Open clicked tab and close the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, toggle, accordion

I'm using JQuery to adjust some accordions. I have the accordion logic ready, but can't get the desired result. I would like that when a tab is clicked, that particular tab opens and the others close if they are open. And if an open tab is clicked, that particular tab closes too. So at any given time, only one tab should be open, but all tabs **can** be closed. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4d5mjgza/

```
 $(function() {
    $('.collapsible-trigger').on('click', function() {
        var panel = $(this).next()[0];
        $('.collapsible-trigger').not($(this)).removeClass('is-open');
        $('.collapsible-content').not(collapsible-content).removeClass('is-open');
        $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
        $(panel).toggleClass("is-open");
    });
});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="collapsibles-wrapper collapsibles-wrapper--border-bottom">
  <button type="button" class="label collapsible-trigger collapsible-trigger-btn collapsible-trigger-btn--borders collapsible--auto-height" aria-controls="content" aria-expanded="false">
    TITLE 1 <span class="collapsible-trigger__icon collapsible-trigger__icon--open" role="presentation">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon--wide icon-chevron-down" viewBox="0 0 28 16">
        <path d="M1.57 1.59l12.76 12.77L27.1 1.59" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>

  </button>
  <div id="content1" class="collapsible-content collapsible-content--all is-open" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="collapsible-content__inner rte">
      hello 1
    </div>
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/*================ Collapsible trigger ================*/

.collapsible-trigger-btn {
  text-align: left !important;
  @include baseTextCenter;
  @include accentFontStack;
  @include accentFontSmallSize;
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: ($gutter / 1.75) 0;

  @include media-query($small) {
    padding: ($gutter / 2) 0;
  }
}

.collapsible-trigger-btn--borders {
  border: 1px solid $colorBorder;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  border-color: #343434 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  font-weight: 600;

  @include media-query($small) {
    font-size: 12px;
  }

  .collapsible-trigger__icon {
    right: 12px;
  }

  @include media-query($medium-up) {
    padding: 15px;

    .collapsible-trigger__icon {
      right: 15px;
    }
  }

  .collapsible-content+& {
    margin-top: -1px;
  }

  +.collapsible-content .collapsible-content__inner {
    @include baseExtraSmallFontStack;
    border: 0px solid $colorBorder;
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;

    @include media-query($medium-up) {
      @include baseSmallFontStack;
      font-size: 13px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }

    @include media-query($small) {
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 1.5;
    }
  }

  +.collapsible-content--expanded {
    margin-bottom: $gutter;

    &:last-child {
      margin-bottom: -1px;
    }
  }
}

.collapsible-trigger-btn--borders-top {
  border-top: 1px solid $colorBorder;
}



  <button type="button" class="label collapsible-trigger collapsible-trigger-btn collapsible-trigger-btn--borders collapsible--auto-height" aria-controls="content" aria-expanded="true">
    TITLE 2 <span class="collapsible-trigger__icon collapsible-trigger__icon--open" role="presentation">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon--wide icon-chevron-down" viewBox="0 0 28 16">
        <path d="M1.57 1.59l12.76 12.77L27.1 1.59" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>

  </button>
  <div id="content2" class="collapsible-content collapsible-content--all is-open" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="collapsible-content__inner rte">
      hello 2
    </div>
  </div>





  <button type="button" class="label collapsible-trigger collapsible-trigger-btn collapsible-trigger-btn--borders" aria-controls="content" aria-expanded="true">
    TITLE 3 <span class="collapsible-trigger__icon collapsible-trigger__icon--open" role="presentation">
      <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon icon--wide icon-chevron-down" viewBox="0 0 28 16">
        <path d="M1.57 1.59l12.76 12.77L27.1 1.59" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
      </svg>
    </span>

  </button>
  <div id="content3" class="collapsible-content collapsible-content--all is-open" style="height: auto;">
    <div class="collapsible-content__inner rte">
      hello 3
    </div>
  </div>
```

Could any of you please lend a helping hand? Would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You forgot to link your CSS for us to use. Can you paste a workable example via snippet?

Comment: @JoelHager Sure thing. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4d5mjgza/

Comment: You don't seem to have any special styling for `is-open` and all of them are already open. I'm not sure exactly what your intended behavior is. Do they *all* start open?

Comment: Title 1 should start open, the others closed. But if say Title 2 is clicked, Title 1 should close. If Title 2 is clicked again, Title 2 too should closed etc

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using jQueryUI's default accordion functionality? https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Unfortunately I’m tied to this HTML because it is built within a theme that I have to use...

Comment: Dang. I was gonna say - This HTML seems *very* sub-optimal for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yup I agree. I’ve been searching around for ages trying to gather information and create a solution for this particular HTML without much luck. Hoping you guys could offer some direction

Comment: Can you edit the CSS as well?

Comment: CSS yes, HTML no unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you have much of code which could be minified. But you can also just extract the core ideas of the following jQuery function.

If you have any questions or problems, you can write a short comment.

```js
$(function() {

  // you can also use the whole item as a trigger with this: $('.accordion .accordion-item')
  $('.accordion .accordion-title').on('click', toggleAccordion);

  function toggleAccordion(event) {
    var target = $(event.target).closest('.accordion-item');

    target.parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-item').not(target).removeClass('is-open');
    target.toggleClass('is-open');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.accordion .accordion-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion .accordion-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .accordion-content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordion .accordion-item.is-open .arrow {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 1
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 2
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="accordion-title">
      TITLE 3
      <span class="arrow"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      CONTENT 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution without an `accordion-item` element**

This is a solution to your problem from your comment. I do not prefer this one, because it would be too unstructured for me. But it's your decision.

I hope that I can help you with this:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.accordion .accordion-title').on('click', toggleAccordion);

  function toggleAccordion(event) {
    var target = $(event.target)
    var content = target.next('.accordion-content');

    content.parent('.accordion').find('.accordion-content').not(content).removeClass('is-open');
    target.toggleClass('is-open');
    content.toggleClass('is-open');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.accordion .accordion-title {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion .accordion-title:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
}

.accordion .accordion-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 15px 15px;
}

.accordion .accordion-content.is-open {
  display: block;
}

.accordion .arrow {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  right: 15px;
  background-color: inherit;
  border: solid #000;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordion .accordion-title.is-open .arrow {
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-title">
    TITLE 1
    <span class="arrow"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    CONTENT 1
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-title">
    TITLE 2
    <span class="arrow"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    CONTENT 2
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-title">
    TITLE 3
    <span class="arrow"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    CONTENT 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Unfortunately the code I'm bound to differs just a little from the code in your solution, because of which I can't tweak it to work. My <div class="accordion-item"> sandwiches only the <div class="accordion-content">, and not both <div class="accordion-title"> and <div class="accordion-content">, as it does in your case. Would you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: @fiddle I would use the `accordion-item` element because of a better structured code. But if you have your well thought-out reasons for this structure, I have added a second solution to my answer.

Comment: @fiddle Please mark the answer to your question if you have found it.

Comment: I have implemented your first solution and the tabs now work. However when I click a tab, the other open one remains open and does not close. I have implemented the provided solution word to word. Any ideas what may be happening?

Comment: Edit: I have figured out where the issue lays: whereas your solution sets 'accordion' as a parent, I have to place the parent in 3 different divs, meaning each div has a different parent. So with the provided function I cannot target the different tabs because they don't belong to the same parent. Any ideas on how to relate the tabs although they have different parents?